# How to create Rock Paper Scissor game with a simple java code using branching and math.random?

Tags: java, branch

I am a noob for java code so please dont mine about my writing, what i am going to do with my code right now is to create a program get the input from user, then print out what user'input (example: if user imput "s" or "S" the program should print out Scissor) and for bot must print out it value (if it generate to #1 it should be said  "I choose Rock") after that tell who is the winner. and if user input wrong command the code will tell that it "invalid"  and default it to rock then result who is the winner this is my code that i have been write so far but it look like nothing is working:

[Update]:I just got the solution so here it is:

```
 Scanner keyb=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please select one of [R/P/S]: ");
        String user = keyb.nextLine();
        int comt=(int)(3*Math.random())+1;
        String comp="";

        if (comt==1){
                comp= "Rock";
        }
        else if (comt==2){
                comp="Paper";
        }
        else if (comt==3){
                comp="Scissors";
        }

        if  (user.equals("R") || user.equals("r")) {
                System.out.println("You choose: Rock");
                user = "Rock";
        }
        else if (user.equals("P")||user.equals("p")) {
                System.out.println("You choose: Paper");
                user = "Paper";
        }
        else if (user.equals("S")||user.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println("You choos: Scissors");
                user = "Scissors";
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("invalid, defaulting to Rock");
             user = "Rock";
        }

        System.out.println("I choose: "+ comp);

        if (user.equals(comp)){
                System.out.println("A tie!");
        }
        else if (user.equals("Rock")) {
                if (comp.equals("Scissors"))
                        System.out.println("Rock beats scissor - you win!");
                else if (comp.equals("Papper"))
                        System.out.println("Paper beats rock - you lose");
        }
        else if (user.equals("Paper")) {
                if (comp.equals("Scissors"))
                        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper- you lose");
                else if (comp.equals("Rock"))
                        System.out.println("Paper beats rock - you win");
        }
        else if (user.equals("Scissors")) {
                if (comp.equals("Papper"))
                        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper - you win!");
                else if (comp.equals("Rock"))
                        System.out.println("Rock beats scissors - you lose!");
        }

        keyb.close();
```

Comment: Please be more precise: in what way(s) is it not working?  In what way(s) does its behavior differ from what you expect?  Examples would probably be helpful here.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank, i had edit the code and specify the issue now.  what i am having problem is the code doesnt show me the result.

Comment: Please provide example(s) of the inputs you have tested.

Comment: @ScottHunter this is what it show: 
'Please select one of [R/P/S]: 
s
You choos scissor
I choose: P'

Comment: @bscouth: First, there's no way that code can show that output. The difference between `You choos: Scissors` and `You choos scissor` may seem unimportant to you, but if you're making the same mistakes with the code, the compiler will not know what you're doing. And similarly, if the code, input, and output you show us are not a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't debug anything for you.

Comment: @abarnert so it mean that the code that i had just edit is still not working flawlessly?? sorry for asking because I am so new to Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some brackets:

```
else if (user.equals("R") || user.equals("r")) {
    if (comp.equals("S"))
        System.out.println("Rock beats scissor - you win!");
    else if (comp.equals("P"))
        System.out.println("Paper beats rock - you lose");
}
else if (user.equals("P")||user.equals("p")) {
    if (comp.equals("S"))
        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper- you lose");
    else if (comp.equals("R")|| comp.equals("r"))
        System.out.println("Paper beats rock - you win");
}
else if (user.equals("S")||user.equals("s")) {
    if (comp.equals("P"))
        System.out.println("Scissors beats paper - you win!");
    else if (comp.equals("R"))
        System.out.println("Rock beats scissors - you lose!");
}
```

Comment: Thank, i had fix it now but it still not show the result?

Comment: I tried your code. It works fine, except that you forgot to define a default value for `user`. After `System.out.println("invalid, defaulting to Rock");` you should add `user = "R";`.

Comment: Thank for replying, yes i had add it to the last branch "else" but it just show me nothing beside"invalid, defaulting to rock"

Comment: this is the result http://i61.tinypic.com/2wmmjv9.jpg i had updated my question code too.

Comment: Did you add it as in your code above? Cause this way it makes no sense. You have to add `user = "R"` in the else branch, where you output `System.out.println("invalid, defaulting to Rock");`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8Uvq13f0